# Disk reads not reduced while running a query again

Tags: oracle

**Case 1:**

I am running a Sql query in oracle, its a simple select statement on a table with no index. The stats information that I got for the query shows a `TABLE FULL ACCESS`, `176k buffer_gets` and `111k disk_reads`. I ran the same query again and checked the stats result, only the time got reduced but there is no change in buffer_gets and disk reads. As the data is cached the time is getting reduced y not buffer and disk reads?

**Case 2:**

Now I have created an index for the table and ran the same query and saw the stats result, I got TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX and few buffer gets and disk reads. when I ran the same query again I got the same result with zero disk reads and reduction in time.

why disk reads not reduced in case 1? When i run a query what are all gets cached? 
As far as I have noticed disk reads remains the same in table access full and joins.

Answer (score 1):

A full scan on a large table generally does not spoil the database cache. That is why in your case 1 the number of disk reads remains the same. In your case 2, you just fetch the data that is needed by using the correct index and that will be cached, proven by your second run where it does not do any disk accesses at all.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the table? If I simplify it, the Oracle buffer cache is a huge hash table, where each cell starts a linked list of pages.

When Oracle accesses the page it first takes table block's physical address (file number, and block id) and computes a hash value of it. Then it traverses the linked list of blocks bound to this particular hash value.

The blocks are ordered by using LRU (with touch count) algorithm. The newest blocks are at the begging of the list.

And now comes the answer: When Oracle sees than the segment size(table) is bigger than 5% the whole buffer cache it puts the blocks at the and of the LRU list. This should prevent the whole buffer cache gets "starved out" by a single query execution. The database is concurrent environment and if a single query execution invalidated all the previously cached data, it would be bad for other users.

PS: I'm not sure about the 5% threshold, the value may vary between Oracle versions.

PS1: you are probably not using ASM storage. Oracle might (or might not) use so called DIRECT file access. When it is `enabled` the database tells to the OS kernel, that disk operations `should not` be cached by OS's buffer cache. When DIRECT_IO is disabled(default option for file storage), then your disk data might by also cached on OS level, but Oracle can not see it.

Comment: Thank u.. Table size exceeds 5% threshold, its around 22%. If u have any detailed doc or link on how data gets stored on buffer cache pls share it.

Comment: I think it was written in "Oracle Core: Essential Internals for DBAs and Developers" by Jonathan Lewis. I'm not sure whether this can be found in official public Oracle documentation.